# Storyboards add a button on window

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard

How do I add a button on window while using storyboards, I want the button to remain always visible on all screens.

I tried adding the image on the window but its not visible.

```
UIWindow *window =[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
[img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[window addSubview:img];
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not added a `UIButton` but have added a `UIView` to `window` in `appdelegate`.

Here you go:

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window)
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];

svc = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame(<some frame>)];
[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:svc];
```

Hope it helps